# Using Varnish with Azure VM load balancing

Tags: linux, azure, virtual-machine, varnish

I'm fairly new to varnish, so hopefully someone might be able to help me out!

Currently I've got 2 load-balanced linux VMs hosted on Windows Azure. They are load-balanced using Azure's own load-balancer for traffic on port 80 using a round robin strategy.

What I would like to do is add Varnish into the mix - however I don't know the best way to fit it into my architecture...

PLAN A

```
                                              Linux VM 1
Varnish (VM) --> Azure Load Balancing ------>
                                              Linux VM 2
```

Varnish sits in front of the load balanced VMs. I think this would do what I would like by caching before going to the back-end....but there's a single point of failure, being varnish. If varnish goes down, then this won't work.

PLAN B

```
                               Varnish (VM) ---------> Linux VM 1
 Azure Load Balancing ------>
                               Varnish (VM) ---------> Linux VM 2
```

Varnish is now load balanced which helps eliminate a single point of failure, but now I have 2 cache VM's which will cost more to host. Also I now have to manage the cache across two different servers.

PLAN C

```
                       Linux VM 1
Varnish (VM) ------>
                       Linux VM 2
```

Get rid of Azure load balancing altogether and use Varnish as a load-balancer in its own right. This would give me more control over load balancing, however (again) - single point of failure.

For any of the experts out there, what from your experience is the best way forward?

Comment: I'm kind of curious - what did you end up doing?

Comment: I didn't in the end, we decided not to use varnish but I would have like to :/ - I've spoken to people who used Varnish and they said either or - it can sit behind / ahead of a predefined loadbalncer or even act as a load-balancer itself! Much I need to learn :)

Comment: I'm in a similar boat - much to learn. :)

I'd think that having Varnish sitting before the Azure load balancer would probably give the best performance. From what I've read, Varnish seems pretty impressive at handling things, and it'd mean that the ALB would end up doing less work. It's always hard to decide where to put the single point of failure, though.